# How do I make findstr show the full file path inline?

Tags: command-line, path, grep, dos, findstr

When I use `grep` I get a list of matching results with the full file path for all the child subdirectories.

When i do this with `findstr` - I don't get the inline results.

My question is: **How do I make `findstr` show the full file path inline?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading *FINDSTR Output* in the comprehensive [List of undocumented features and limitations of FINDSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/3439404) by *Dave Benham* aka [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham):

> ... When printed, the fileName will always include any path
>   information provided. Additional path information will be added if the
>   `/S` option is used. The printed path is **always relative** to the
>   provided path, or relative to the current directory if none provided.

Hence, provide *absolute path*. For instance: instead of

```
findstr /S /M /I /C:"string being searched for" *.txt
```

use

```
findstr /S /M /I /C:"string being searched for" "%CD%\*.txt"
```

Of course, all `/S /M /I /C:` switches given in the above example are *optional*:

```
d:\bat\files>findstr "success" *.txt
netuser.txt:The command completed successfully.
typeperf.txt:The command completed successfully.

d:\bat\files>findstr "success" "%CD%\*.txt"
d:\bat\files\netuser.txt:The command completed successfully.
d:\bat\files\typeperf.txt:The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: A link to the original quote would be nice, which is where SS64 got the information. Especially since the original post was on StackOverlow - http://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053.

Comment: Also, I believe the OP wants the file name prefixed before each matching line, which would rule out the `/M` option.

Comment: @dbenham please forgive my dark on the quote origin; see my edit on the `/M` switch as well:)

Answer (score 2):

```
findstr "search string" %cd%\*
```